# Can a <button> be styled so that it flows within text like an <a> or <span> would?

Tags: html, css

I'd like to style a `<button>` element so that it looks and behaves like a link.  In particular, I'd like the button's content to flow within paragraph text in the same way that an anchor or span element would.  The basic css for making a "link-like" style, resetting the browser's defaults and adding link-ish styling, is something like this:

```css
button.link-like {
  /* reset browser defaults */
  border-style: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline;
  white-space: normal;
  /* link look */
  color: #0000ee;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><title>Test button links</title></head>
<body>
  <div style="width: 200px; outline: 1px solid red;">
    This is a <a href=''>just a normal link that wraps to two lines.</a>
  </div>
  <div style="width: 200px; outline: 1px solid red;">
    This is a <button class="link-like">button that should behave like a link</button>.
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

However, as you can see from running the snippet above, the button's content does not flow within the paragraph, but instead breaks into its own block.  It appears as though despite the `display: inline`, the button is retaining something of an `inline-block` behavior within the paragraph.

Can a button be styled such that its contents flows within a paragraph like a link?

Comment: I'm sorry if this sounds silly - but why? You can get a link to do pretty much anything you need (i.e. behave like a button) using JS - unless this is not an option.

Comment: @alpharomeo Maybe OP wants to keep semantics intact. If that's the case, the real button could be hidden visually, and the link-as-a-button could carry `aria-hidden="true"` to keep things tidy. Not ideal, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try `display: contents;`

```css
button.link-like {
  /* reset browser defaults */
  border-style: none;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 0;
  display: contents;
  white-space: normal;
  /* link look */
  color: #0000ee;
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 200px; outline: 1px solid red;">
  This is a <a href=''>just a normal link that wraps to two lines.</a>
</div>
<div style="width: 200px; outline: 1px solid red;">
  This is a <button class="link-like">button that should behave like a link</button>.
</div>
```

Comment: Just be aware of the accessibilty issues on using display: contents https://www.last-child.com/displaycontents-and-the-impact-on-accessibility/

Comment: Hmm, and the underline style appears to get skipped in firefox.  This may be a great way to do this in the future but looks pretty bleeding-edge right now.

Comment: The spec for `display: contents` https://drafts.csswg.org/css-display/#unbox is useful in characterizing how the core problem here relates to the "principle box" of a button element.